# to save docx as pdf in c# (.net) with policy label

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, office-interop

i'm converting .docx files to .pdf with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word library in C# (.Net Framework 4.6.2)

my code is:

```
    public static void DOCtoPDF(string docFullPath, string pdfFullPath)
    {
        Application appWord = new Application();
        var wordDocument = appWord.Documents.Open(docFullPath);

        wordDocument.SaveAs2(pdfFullPath, WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF);
        wordDocument.Close();
        appWord.Quit();
    }
```

i'm taking this error while i am saving doc file:

[image]

how to solve this problem?

Comment: Side note: I really hope you've added "asp.net" tag for fun and not really planning to use that code server side... (dialog you are facing is just on tiny example why using Office product is not supported for  headless sessions)

Comment: oww.. i only tried localhost.. :) i didnt try in server...

i m trying now ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem..

it's trying to save wordDocument so it show me that dialog..

i wrote

```
wordDocument.Close(false);
```

instead of

```
wordDocument.Close();
```

now, it is not trying to save my original word document. 
it only convert to pdf. :)

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative approach to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word library, you may want to check out [GemBox.Document library](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document).

For example like this:

```
public static void DOCtoPDF(string docFullPath, string pdfFullPath)
{
    DocumentModel wordDocument = DocumentModel.Load(docFullPath);
    wordDocument.Save(pdfFullPath);
}
```

Comment: All these 3rd party products are very expansive.